# R; plot basic: multicharts: Drawing a box at the oma boundary

Tags: r

I have a number of plot charts and I would like to enclose then in a box as defined by the oma boundary inner margin (not the page border).
I tried adding box.figure but that did not work

```
layout(matrix(c(1:10),5,2, byrow = TRUE), widths=c(1), heights=c(1))
par(oma=c(4,1,2,1))
par(mar=c(1,4,3,1))
for( n in 1:10) {
plot(1:10)
}

box("figure", col="forestgreen")
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use '**outer**' instead of figure, it should give you a red box on entire plot. The **forestgreen** color was not visible clearly, also you may try for more bright colors like **red/green**. You will observe the box will glow on boundaries:

```
layout(matrix(c(1:10),5,2, byrow = TRUE), widths=c(1), heights=c(1))

par(oma=c(4,1,2,1))
par(mar=c(1,4,3,1))

for( n in 1:10) {
  plot(1:10)
  
}
box('outer',col = 'red')
```

**EDIT** after edit in question:

```
box('inner', col = 'red')
```

Using inner option in box can give margins around the box from inside, the outer option gives margins on outside. I am hoping this is what OP is expecting. Thanks

**Output: inner**:

[image]

**Output: Outer**:

[image]

Comment: That is great. Thanks.